# Possible Firebase bug with .onDisconnect() when running Opera?

Tags: firebase

First off I apologize if there has already been a similar question before, I honestly couldn't find any.

I'm currently developing a chat using Firebase and thanks to the decent docs I'm making good progress so far, so this isn't really the issue here. However, while testing I stumbled across a little issue that might possibly be a bug.

For managing presence in my chat, I am pushing values to a location that corresponds to my user's unique ID. This pushed value is then removed on disconnect.
By doing it this way, I can reliably determine a user's status without worrying about his number of concurrent connections to my Firebase (i.e. browser tabs).

This is actually working fine with Firefox, Chrome and Safari, but there seems to be an issue with Opera. When using Opera, if you close the tab in which the chat is running, the value that **should** be removed on disconnect is **not**. It will be removed eventually after like 2 minutes or so, but it is taking way too long, considering that the same thing is happening instantaneously when using another browser.

Out of curiosity I've tried the [presence example](https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#example/presence) using Opera and I was able to reproduce the exact same behavior. If I open the corresponding Firebase in another tab, then run the example, enter a name and finally close the tab that the example is running in, I can see that the value in the corresponding Firebase is not removed as I close the tab.

I would appreciate if you could tell me if this is just me doing something wrong or if it is actually a bug.

Regards
Muddy

Comment: You didn't mention the versions, which would be important. However, the onDisconnect is run at the Firebase servers (not locally) so it wouldn't be browser specific. I'm guessing that for some reason you're not using websockets and the server has to wait for a TCP connect? Have you tried waiting 5-10m and seeing if the disconnect fires?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opera has a different model for page transitions than all other browsers. Most browsers fire events when loading and leaving a page. Opera actually keeps old pages hot in memory in order to make the back button faster. When you click "back" in opera it's actually resuming the old page.

As a result, there's no way for us to know exactly when someone has left a page in Opera. As a result, we're forced to simply wait for a server timeout to determine someone has left.

So, short answer, onDisconnect operations DO work in Opera, but they might take a couple of minutes to take affect. In all other browsers the operations will happen immediately if the connection was terminated cleanly, and after a few minutes if it was not.

Comment: Ah okay, I wasn't aware of that, thank you for clearing this up. Well, this isn't that much of a problem anyway. I would consider it an inconvenience at best, I was just curious about why this was happening.