# Firebase latency in Opera

Tags: firebase

For some strange reason, when using Opera, the latency to Firebase servers is very high.

I have tested on Chrome, Firefox and Opera(12.14) with a script similar to this one:

```
# CoffeeScript
p = new Firebase('somelocation')
ping = 0
setInterval =>
  t = Date.now()
  p.set ping, (d) =>
    ping = Date.now() - t
, 2000
```

On Chrome and Firefox, the latency is around 150-160 (I live in Poland so that's actually pretty good) but the same script running on Opera gives me latency of 1000 or more. It also seems to be affecting the onDisconnect() mechanism which triggers **minutes** after disconnecting.

Comment: There's another SO post detailing the onDisconnect behavior in Opera: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16234185/possible-firebase-bug-with-ondisconnect-when-running-opera

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. Should've searched more thoroughly. The main question still remains though (high latency).

Comment: The latency concern is also addressed in the first answer of the question that Kato linked. It has to do with the manner in which Opera handles the connections—which is, unfortunately, out of our control.